# Autoplot adjust scale Y or X

Tags: r

In this plot, is there a way to adjust the Y scale (1000, 10.000, 100.000)?

```
x <- mdeaths+runif(n = length(mdeaths), min = 5000, max = 99523)*1000


#--- Only example
x1 <- auto.arima(x)

x2 <- forecast(x1, h = 12, level = 0.80)

autoplot(x2) # works

autoplot(x2/100000) # dont works

Error in x2/100000 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

***Edit:***
Example
[image: Example]

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you just want other labels?

Comment: I update the post, i was not able to put an image in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you exactly want, but since `autoplot()` is a function of the `ggplot2` package you can apply `ggplot2` functions.

The "scaling" by `100000` should take place before `auto.arima()`.

```
x1 <- auto.arima(x / 100000)
x2 <- forecast(x1, h = 12, level = 0.80)
```

With `scales::comma` you can disable scientific notation what you probably mean by "adjust". And set breaks to a logarithmic sequence you can achieve with `breaks=10^(0:ceiling(log10(max(x))))`

Altogether this gives you:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
autoplot(x2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 10^(0:ceiling(log10(max(x)))), labels = comma)
```

***Yielding***

[image]

Or try a logarithmic scale with `autoplot(x2) + scale_y_log10(breaks = 10^(0:ceiling(log10(max(x)))), labels = comma)`.